# Sympy library solve to an unknown variable

Tags: python, sympy

I have derived some equations with some variables. I want to solve to an unknown variable. I am using Sympy. My code is as follows:

```
import sympy as syp

import math as m
#this is the unknown variable that I want to find
C0 = syp.Symbol('C0')
#Known variables
D0 = 0.874

theta2 = 10.0
fi2 = 80.0

theta1 = (theta2/180.0)*m.pi
fi1 = (fi2/180.0)*m.pi
#Definitions of 6 different equations all of them in respect to CO.
C_t = 5*m.pi*(D0+4*C0)

St123 = 1.5*theta1*(D0+2*C0)

St45 = fi1*(D0+7*C0)

l1 = syp.sqrt((0.5*(D0+4*C0)-0.5*D0*m.cos(theta1))**2 + (0.5*D0*m.sin(theta1))**2)

l2 = syp.sqrt((0.5*(D0+6*C0)-0.5*(D0+2*C0)*m.cos(theta1))**2 + (0.5*(D0+2*C0)*m.sin(theta1))**2)

l3 = syp.sqrt((0.5*(D0+8*C0)-0.5*(D0+4*C0)*m.cos(theta1))**2 + (0.5*(D0+4*C0)*m.sin(theta1))**2)
#Definition of the general relationship between the above functions. Here C0 is unknown and C_b
C_b = C_t + 6*C0 + 3*(l1+l2+l3) - 3*St123 - 3*St45
#for C_b = 10.4866, find C0
syp.solve(C_b - 10.4866, C0)
```

As observed, I want to solve the C_b relationship to C0. Until the last line my code works fine. When I ran the whole script it seems that takes ages to calculate the C0. I dont have any warning message but I dont have any solution either. Would anybody suggest an alternative or a possible solution? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It is a bad idea just to dump your code and expect a meaningful answer. Could you try to create a minimal example and explain what should be happening and what you have tried? Also, I see that you are actually dealing with numeric equations. In this case why are you using sympy (a symbolic library) instead of numpy/scipy which are better suited for numerics?

Comment: Apologise for the way I dropped my code and any inconvenience this may caused. What I want to do is to find C0. I have 6 functions all of them in respect to C0 (C_t, St123, St45, l1,l2,l3). The last function shows the relationship between those 6 functions (C_b). If we substitute C_t, St123, etc terms in the C_b equation then we will end up with a big equation with C_b and C0 unknowns. At the last line what I m trying to do is to find the C0 when C_b is 10.4. Do you think that with SciPy will be much easier? Thnaks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have mentioned in a comment this problem is numerical in nature, so it is better to try to solve it with numpy/scipy. Nonetheless it is an amusing example of how to do numerics in sympy so here is one suggested workflow.

First of all, if it was not for the relative complexity of the expressions here, scipy would have been definitely the better option over sympy. But the expression is rather complicated, so we can first simplify it in `sympy` and only then feed it to `scipy`:

```
>>> C_b
38.0∗C0
+3.0∗((0.17∗C0+0.076)∗∗2+(2.0∗C0+0.0066)∗∗2)∗∗0.5
+3.0∗((0.35∗C0+0.076)∗∗2+(2.0∗C0+0.0066)∗∗2)∗∗0.5
+3.0∗((2.0∗C0+0.0066)∗∗2+0.0058)∗∗0.5
+9.4

>>> simplify(C_b)
38.0∗C0
+3.0∗(4.0∗C0∗∗2+0.027∗C0+0.0058)∗∗0.5
+3.0∗(4.1∗C0∗∗2+0.053∗C0+0.0058)∗∗0.5
+3.0∗(4.2∗C0∗∗2+0.08∗C0+0.0058)∗∗0.5
+9.4
```

Now given that you are not interested in symbolics and that the simplification was not that good, it would be useless to continue using sympy instead of scipy, but if you insist you can do it.

```
>>> nsolve(C_b - 10.4866, C0, 1) # for numerical solution
0.00970963412692139
```

If you try to use `solve` instead of `nsolve` you will just waste a lot of resources in searching for a symbolic solution (that may not even exist in elementary terms) when a numeric one is instantaneous.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I really appreciate. Actually I was expecting a value around 0.05. When I change the radians to degrees my solution is better but with negative symbol. I was expecting to take two solutions, one negative and one positive so I want to hold the positive. Do you think that SciPy is better? I was trying to find how someone can solve to an unknown variable but I cannot find something helpful yet.  SymPy seems to do it better bu t I dont know how to take two roots.

Comment: Numerical solvers are mostly doing some fancy version of the Newton method (check wikipedia), so the need an initial value to start searching ("1" above). If you play with the initial value you might find another root. You can also plot these functions to get a better idea of how they look like. And the question about `scipy`: `nsolve` is more straightforward than the root finding or optimization routines in `scipy`, but scipy gives you much more control over the numeric details. Sympy on the other hand supports symbolics which you can not do in scipy. This problem is however to0 complicated.